# is there a graph database that automatically generates restful endpoints for each node?

Tags: rest, graph-databases, orientdb, arangodb

I'm looking at ArangoDB and OrientDB and other graph databases and need to know which supports ability to to store hierarchial data (Trees, file directory like) and then expose it via a REST api automatically or with little tinkering.

so if I go to http://localhost.com/parent/ it should list all the children on this level. or http://localhost.com/parent/child4/child1/leaf should give me a the leaf node.

Comment: Do you need graph features or just the hierarchical structure? I. e. do you want to run traversal on your structure? Or just query it using the REST API?

Comment: @fceller Priority is on the REST api. I do need to eventually run a full traversal of the tree, visiting every branch. I could get away with a hierarchial structure if the REST api component is usable. I need something that will let me access each parent and leaf node in a RESTful url scheme that reflects the hierarchy. `localhost/parent/child/leaf`

Comment: Understood, will try to create an example.

Comment: why the hell is this question offtopic? isn't stackoverflow a site for programmers anymore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ArangoDB won't generate this REST API automatically for you, but it can be generated with little effort.
If you store the connections between nodes in an edge collection, you can expose them via a small Foxx application like the following. The code assumes you have your nodes stored in a collection "v" and the connections between nodes stored in a collection "e".

```
(function() {
  "use strict";

  // Initialise a new FoxxApplication.
  var FoxxApplication = require("org/arangodb/foxx").Controller,
    controller = new FoxxApplication(applicationContext),
    db = require("org/arangodb").db;

  controller.get("/*", function (req, res) {
    var nodeCollection = db.v;
    var edgeCollection = db.e;

    var requestedNode = req.suffix.pop();

    try {
      var node = nodeCollection.document(requestedNode);
      var subNodes = edgeCollection.outEdges(nodeCollection.name() + "/" + requestedNode);

      res.json({ node: node, subNodes: subNodes });
    }
    catch (err) {
      res.json("oops, some error happened!");
    }
  });
}());
```

I set up a few example nodes using the following JavaScript:

```
db._create("v");
db._createEdgeCollection("e");

/* nodes */
db.v.save({ _key: "root" });
db.v.save( { _key: "subnode1" });
db.v.save( { _key: "subnode2" });
db.v.save( { _key: "subnode3" });
db.v.save( { _key: "subnode1-1" });
db.v.save( { _key: "subnode1-2" });
db.v.save( { _key: "subnode1-3" });
db.v.save( { _key: "subnode2-1" });
db.v.save( { _key: "subnode2-2" });

/* connections */
db.e.save("v/root", "v/subnode1", { });
db.e.save("v/root", "v/subnode2", { });
db.e.save("v/root", "v/subnode3", { });
db.e.save("v/subnode1", "v/subnode1-1", { });
db.e.save("v/subnode1", "v/subnode1-2", { });
db.e.save("v/subnode1", "v/subnode1-3", { });
db.e.save("v/subnode2", "v/subnode2-1", { });
db.e.save("v/subnode2", "v/subnode2-2", { });
```

If the Foxx application is mounted, it will allow you to fetch data of any node by putting the node _key into the URL, e.g. http://example.com:8529/myapp/root or http://example.com:8529/myapp/subnode2-2

The above API will return a node's data and all subnodes for the requested node. It can easily be changed to behave differently, e.g. to look at the full request URI and fetch the nodes by each part of the path (e.g. "root/subnode1/subnode1-1"). This can be achieved by iterating over req.suffix if required. Though it is not necessary if a node's _key is already known and passed via URL.

It will also be hard to distinguish between nodes and leaf nodes just by looking at the URL, so I suggest adding a URL parameter "subNodes=true" to indicate subnodes should be returned. If the URL parameter is omitted, no subnodes need to queried and returned.